# How to programmatically set up EventsBridge events for Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js, aws-event-bridge, aws-policies

I have set up 2 lambda functions, deployed with AWS SAM. The first one uses the JS AWS SDK to run [`putRule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putRule-property) and [`putTarget`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putTargets-property) to trigger the second lambda with a cron job. When I run the first lambda, I see both the rule and target correctly set up in EventsBridge.

I also create the following permission for the second Lambda in my AWS SAM template

```
InvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref MyLambda
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: 'events.amazonaws.com'
```

and can see the Policy in the console
[image: Policy statement that allows event.amazonaws.com to invoke the Lambda]

The only result I see of this cron event (at the timestamp I've chosen for the rule) is a failed invocation of the second Lambda, and CloudWatch [doesn't provide any useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106603/14381282)

Any idea of why this is failing or how to retrieve any error? Might "events.amazonaws.com" be the wrong `Principal` for that?

I am looking into EventSourceMapping but I can't see my case anywhere in the docs